# Как отключить бота discord от голосового канала?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Есть проблема при отключении бота от голосового чата:

```py
import discord
import asyncio

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@Bot.command()
async def play(ctx):
    await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
    await ctx.message.delete()


@Bot.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect(channel)
```

После использования первой команды бот успешно заходит в голосовой канал, но после использования второй команды выпадает ошибка:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
> exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
> 'disconnect'

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Решилось все случайно)

```py
@Bot.command()
async def play(ctx):
    await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
    await ctx.message.delete()


@Bot.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
    await ctx.message.delete()
```